# R: indexing by T/F vector returns more values than it should -why?

Tags: r

I stumbled upon something weird, where I don't know why r behaves in the way it does.
I have a vector, with values from 1:100 (vec100). Now I only want to get the values lower than 50. Normally, I'd write vec100[vec100<50] and would be happy. Today, however, I used the assigned the logical vec100<50 to an object x for reasons of demonstration. To show, that this approach is dangerous, as it selects the positions and not the values per se, I selected x from another vector vec2 <- c(vec100,20,50,100,10). Funnily, it also returns those added values although they are out of the range of x, and I don't find an explanation why it does that.

```
vec <- 1:100
x <- vec<50 #logical vector of length 100
vec[x] #selects the values just as
vec[vec<50] #does

#now let's add some values
vec2 <- c(vec, 20,50,100,10)
vec2[x]
#returns:
# [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18        19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
#[30]  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47       48  49  20  50 100  10

# so adds 20, 50, 100, 10 although those positions are not in x

#though it omits those new positions (not in x) when I look at the values which are not TRUE in x

vec2[x==F]
# [1]  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  #73  74  75  76  77  78
#[30]  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

confused greetings,
Lea

Comment: This is the recycling behavior effect: the first values of `x` are `TRUE`. Also, instead of `x==FALSE`, it's better to negate `!x`.

Comment: Try `vec3 <- 1:151; vec3[x]` to see the effect of recycling: you will not get `150` or `151` appearing because the second cycle of `x` has become false

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, tipps and the illustrative examples Rui and Henry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is basically due to recycling of vector when one of the vector is of lesser length. i.e. the lesser length vector recycles from the beginning.  Here the 'x' is a logical vector of the same length as `vec`, but, when we concatenated four more elements to create 'vec2', the 'x' begins from the beginning i.e. x[1:4] is recycled.  It can be checked by

```
v1 <- vec2[x]
v2 <- vec2[c(x, x[1:4])]
identical(v1, v2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! Now it makes sense to me, should have thought about it earlier